# OpenID Connect authorize endpoint XHR vs hidden iframe

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, refresh-token

I was wondering what the primary reason was for using a hidden iframe with `prompt=none` when silently refreshing the tokens in OpenID Connect? As the spec [1] says that the `/authorize` endpoint must support `POST` could this not be done via an XHR request?

[1] https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthorizationEndpoint (3.1.2.1. Authentication Request)

Comment: This is an implementation detail that the software vendor chose and not part of the spec. The presentation or lack thereof to the user is not part of OAuth. I have even seen implementations that show a pop box.

Comment: Thanks John, makes sense. Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Not sure, but I don't think I can accept a comment?

Comment: I just posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation detail that the software vendor chose and not part of the spec.

The presentation or lack thereof to the user is not part of OAuth. I have even seen implementations that show a popup box.